# How do you load() with jQuery the way you would include() with PHP inline code like this?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE AT BOTTOM
I am used to using a selector that involves an id or class, so not even sure this is possible at least the function I am thinking. I have a separate file called replist.html that I hold data in a one-to-one relationship like this (partial list of 35,000 lines)...

```
'Illinois': 'joesmoe',
'Nevada': 'messytess',
<!-- start of new zip codes -->
'01001': 'julsguls',
'01002': 'julsguls',
```

I initially pulled the file into page I am using script on with an include_once(), but now am working on modifications to alter for Mobile devices and their handling of location detection (I am converting IP to zip). Because of the nature, I am looking to access data through client-side script over the PHP. Here is what I have so far...

```
<script>
...
<?php
if(!(($detect->isMobile()))) {  ?>
            var reps = {
            <?php include_once('repList.html'); ?>
            };
 <?php
}
else { ?>
    <!-- custom mobile location detection here --> 
    reps = {***would like to get load() here***}; 
<?php } ?>
...
</script>
```

...the else I am looking to add mobile location detection script, then **load()** my repList.html file.

I have simplified the else to just focus on how to get my load() in there. If anyone has a better jQuery, other JavaScript library or any client side solution I am open. The script I plan to use pre-this process is client side and why I can not use PHP as I was using.

I believe I will keep the PHP and go with...

```
var reps_load = {<?php include_once('repList.html'); ?>};

<?php
if(!(($detect->isMobile()))) {  ?>
    var reps = reps_load;
 <?php
}
else {
...
```

Comment: You can't load files inline, the JS will be executed in the client and not have access to the files on the server.  Look at Modernizr/yepnope for a JS solution.  The best solution for this type of problem has too many factors to make blind suggestions.

Comment: @MattWhipple I was hoping that there is a solution like $('this').load('repList.html'); .. wishful thinking.

Comment: You'd be able to load a file with an AJAX request, but that is almost certainly **not** the answer to your problem.  It sounds like your best first approach would be to re-evaluate ways to communicate that information to PHP.  Take a longer look at if the headers of requests provide the information you need (they should), otherwise you may want to consider redirecting mobile devices to a hostname alias which PHP would be able to see.  These are both assuming responsive design isn't an option.

Comment: @MattWhipple Your right, I should be able to recycle once what I am already going to include regardless of my selection is in the if/else. I believe I got ahead of myself because the existence of backbone and node have made me obsessed with learning JavaScript only options lol.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual `load()` does:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched
>   element.

So that cannot assign anything to your javascript variable.

You could [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the data server-side and use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead, assigning the returned value to your variable in the callback function.

But you would call another php file that in turn reads your data and prepares it.

Something like:

```
else
{
?>
  <!-- custom mobile location detection here -->
  var reps;
  $.getJSON('script_that_returns_data_as_json.php', function(data) {
    reps = data;
    // you might need to process it to get it the form you want...
  });
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method uses only plain javascript, but it works even across sites in case your data is on a different domain.
You can prepend a file with the data included as JSON or javascript variables

```
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.src="your_url.js"
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.insertBefore(script,head.firstChild)
```

and then your data file could look something like:

```
items=[
{"state":"Illinois","name":"joesmoe"},
{"zip":"01001", "value":"julsquls"}
];
```

which can be accessed by:

```
for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    if(items[i].state) /*state stuff*/;
    if(items[i].zip) /*zip stuff*/;
}
```

Comment: The only thing is that look-up key would be much slower and I have much data.

Comment: @Shane  You can store the data however you want, this was just an example, but its still faster than parsing html.  ex. `states={illinois:"joeshamoe",iowa:"jillchill",...}`,zips={z00001:"something",z00002:"something else"}` then use states.illinois or zips.z##### ... it all depends on the rest of your code

Comment: btw those are javascript associative arrays, so you would probably want to access them as such:  `alert(zips["z"+zip]);` where zip is a numerical zip code (you can't start associative arrays with numbers, thus the "z"+)